# Hibernate: Cannot resolve table in entity class

Tags: java, hibernate, maven, intellij-idea

I'm using Intellij Idea 2018.1.3

I've done small maven app for testing hibernate with annotation mapping but i have an issue with names of table and it's columns. They marked with red stripes with clarification "Cannot resolve table/column '...'"

I think that it's trouble with settings of Hibernate in Idea but where can it be?

I've created hibernate.cfg.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE hibernate-configuration PUBLIC
    "-//Hibernate/Hibernate Configuration DTD 3.0//EN"
    "http://hibernate.sourceforge.net/hibernate-configuration-3.0.dtd">

<hibernate-configuration>
<session-factory>
    <property name="hibernate.connection.driver_class"> org.postgresql.Driver</property>
    <property name="hibernate.connection.url">jdbc:postgresql://localhost:5432/cowbull1</property>
    <property name="hibernate.dialect">org.hibernate.dialect.PostgreSQL9Dialect</property>
    <property name="hibernate.connection.username">cowbull_admin</property>
    <property name="hibernate.connection.password">cowbull</property>
    <property name="hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto">update</property>
    <property name="show_sql">true</property>
    <mapping class="org.mycode.entities.User"/>
</session-factory>
</hibernate-configuration>
```

And i have an entity class:

```
import javax.persistence.*;

@Entity
@Table(name = "users")
public class User {

    @Id
    @Column(name = "id")
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private Long id;
    @Column(name = "nickname")
    private String nickname;
    @Column(name = "password")
    private String password;
    //getters, setters, constructors
}
```

HibernateUtil class:

```
import org.hibernate.SessionFactory;
import org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration;

public class HibernateUtil {
    private static final SessionFactory sessionFactory = buildSessionFactory();

    private static SessionFactory buildSessionFactory() {
        try {
            return new Configuration().configure().buildSessionFactory();
    }
        catch (Throwable ex) {
            System.err.println("Initial SessionFactory creation failed." + ex);
            throw new ExceptionInInitializerError(ex);
        }
    }

    public static SessionFactory getSessionFactory() {
        return sessionFactory;
    }
}
```

Main class:

```
import org.hibernate.Session;
import org.myapp.entities.User;
import org.myapp.util.HibernateUtil;

public class App {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        System.out.println("maven + hibernate + postgresql");
        Session session = HibernateUtil.getSessionFactory().openSession();

        session.beginTransaction();
        User user = new User();
        user.setNickname("Dima");
        user.setPassword("123456");
        session.save(user);
        session.getTransaction().commit();
        session.close();
    }
}
```

pom.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
     xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
     xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0     http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
<modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

<groupId>org.myapp</groupId>
<artifactId>cowbull1</artifactId>
<version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>

<dependencies>
    <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.hibernate/hibernate-core -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
        <artifactId>hibernate-core</artifactId>
        <version>5.3.2.Final</version>
    </dependency>
    <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.springframework/spring-web -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-web</artifactId>
        <version>5.0.7.RELEASE</version>
    </dependency>
    <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.springframework/spring-webmvc -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-webmvc</artifactId>
        <version>5.0.7.RELEASE</version>
    </dependency>
    <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.postgresql/postgresql -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.postgresql</groupId>
        <artifactId>postgresql</artifactId>
        <version>42.2.4</version>
    </dependency>
    <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/postgresql/postgresql -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>postgresql</groupId>
        <artifactId>postgresql</artifactId>
        <version>9.1-901-1.jdbc4</version>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>
```

I've defined hibernate module and facet in project settings.

App runs good and it puts an appropriate entry to a table.

Upd: I've already connected to database through idea's editor and it works well.

Answer (score 3):

Just IDE config. You can run program and don't worry about error

1. **Ctrl + All + Shift + S** to open Project Structure
2. in Project Settings click **Modules** -> click button green  **+**
3. select **JPA** -> Default JPA Provider select **Hibernate** -> **OK**

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 1):

This answer can help you with that.

You just need to point IDE to right data source :

https://stackoverflow.com/a/60534314/8536903

Answer (score 0):

As you said, this is not an error that prevents your code to compile. This error means that the editor is not aware of your tables and their columns. Add Database menus to your editor from View/Tools Window/Database. Then assign a data source through the green sign. if the editor successfully connect to your database, those error will go out and also you can use the advantage of the code completion. Another thing, if you had any changes in your database, you can inform the editor by refreshing the datasource.

Comment: Thanks for answer! I forgot to write that i've already connected to database through idea's editor and it works well. But i continue to have an issue in topic.