# Cannot resolve table "'xx"" in spring boot application

Tags: spring-boot, intellij-idea

I'm trying to run a spring boot app, but intellij is showing me an error:

> "Cannot resolve table TB_PRODUTO"

Intellij it's giving a tip to assign a datasource, but the list is empty

[image]

what could be the problem?

Comment: You need to add your datasources manually to IDEA. Did you?

Answer (score 27, accepted):

Try add your database to IDE:

[image]

Then assign it as data source:

[image]

Comment: Just in case someone met the same problem as me, I was wrongly imported `org.hibernate.annotations.Table;` instead of `javax.persistence.*;`, which with hibernate it gives no way to name a `@Table`.

Answer (score 30):

You can turn off this validation from JPA facet settings.

Just go to Intellij IDEA settings/Editor/Inspections
and uncheck "unresolved database references in annotations".

[image: Intellij Settings Screenshot]

Answer (score 6):

I resolved going into view -> tool windows -> database.

Intellij needs that you put manually the database source.

Answer (score 5):

file => setting => Editor = Inspections => JPA => uncheck "unresolved database references in annotations".and the problem will be solved

Answer (score 2):

In my case I just had to select a default schema. Right click on the database -> properties -> schemas -> select your schema.

Answer (score 1):

If you have recently added database objects then JPA may not be detecting them yet - use view - tool windows - database and click the refresh button.