# JPA cannot create table automatically

Tags: java, spring-boot

I have an entity and I want JPA to create a table for me.

```java
import jakarta.persistence.Entity;
import jakarta.persistence.GeneratedValue;
import jakarta.persistence.Id;
import jakarta.persistence.Table;
import lombok.AllArgsConstructor;
import lombok.Builder;
import lombok.Data;
import lombok.NoArgsConstructor;

@Entity
@Data
@Builder
@AllArgsConstructor
@NoArgsConstructor
@Table(name = "_user")
public class User {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue
    private Integer id;
    private String firstname;
    private String lastname;
    private String email;
    private String password;
}
```

IntelliJ gives me the error: *Cannot resolve table '_user'*

I have assigned it to the correct data source and my database connection works fine.

**application.properties.yml**

```yaml
spring:
  datasource:
    url: jdbc:postgresql://localhost:5432/jwt_security
    username: postgres
    password: password
    driver-class-name: org.postgresql.Driver
  jpa:
    hibernate:
      ddl-auto: create
    show-sql: true
    properties:
      hibernate:
        format_sql: true
    database: postgresql
    database-platform: org.hibernate.dialect.PostgreSQLDialect
```

This is how it looks like:

[image]
What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Is the user the table name that doesn't create?

Comment: @K.Nicholas the table name should be `_user` and this is not getting created.

Comment: I'm pretty sure `User` has a table name will give you endless problems.

Comment: @K.Nicholas that's correct. `user` is a table name and that's why I use `_user`. However, I also tried it with many other names. Still the same issue.

Comment: assign it to the correct data source and database connection works fine.

Comment: Is it an error when your spring application starts up or just an IDE error? For the later this post might help - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58666411/cannot-resolve-table-xx-in-spring-boot-application

Comment: @Neeraj no there is no error when I run the application. IntelliJ shows the error on `_user` and this is assigned to the data source `postgres@localhost`, which is correct.

Comment: did you run the spring application and seen anything regarding sql ddl in the logs? It won't exist until that happened and there's obviously no way to resolve a table in the intellij db browser when it doesn't exist yet

Comment: @zapl I don't get any logs at all. I have just manually created the table. Now the error is gone but my table remains empty and I don't even get the SQL code. Seems like application.properties.yml is getting entirely ignored.

Comment: Can you remove spring.jpa.database and spring.jpa.database-platform as these properties are auto injected by default as per connection. and add debug=true as additional property. Then try

Comment: @SaurabhSingh I tried the same but I see no changes.

Comment: What about logs on enabling debug, did you find any error/warning?

Comment: @xRay did you try the stackoverflow  link which tries to resolve the intellij error... I think this is more a ide feature which is not working properly?

Answer (score 0):

Ok, I finally got the solution and it seems like, I made the following mistakes.

1. The file `application.properties.yml` was entirely ignored because the file name should be `application.yml` instead.
2. My main class was using the annotation `@SpringBootApplication(exclude = {DataSourceAutoConfiguration.class })` (I did not mention this in my question, my bad!) caused the issue. Instead, it should be `@SpringBootApplication` only.
3. IDE showed me the error because the table was not created yet. After running the app, the table will be created and then also the error will be removed. However, to avoid this error, although the table has not been created yet, you can use `@Entity(name = "_user")` instead. It works the same.